# delphi - stack overflow error while clicking tab key from a combo edit

Tags: delphi, stack-overflow

I have a 3-tier application written in delphi xe2. While entering data on a combo edit and hitting the tab key, the application is automatically exiting with an error message `stack overflow`. I have attached the code in combo edit exit event:

```
Procedure TFormSalesReturn.ComboEditBillNumberExit(Sender: TObject);
Begin
   Try
      LabelBillNumber.Font.Style := LabelBillNumber.Font.Style - [fsBold];
      dBillDiscountPercentage := 0;
      If (ComboEditBillNumber.Text <> '') Then
      Begin
         If (ComboEditBillNumber.Modified) Then
         Begin
            Try
               If Pos('/', Trim(ComboEditBillNumber.Text)) = 0 Then
                  ComboEditBillNumber.Text := FormMDIMain.sBranchcode +
                     FormMDIMain.sCurrentFinancialYear + '/' +
                     FormMDIMain.FuncStrZero(Trim(ComboEditBillNumber.Text), 6);
            Except
               on E: Exception Do
               begin
                  MessageDlg('Cannot Load Bill' + E.Message, mtError,
                     [MbOk], 0);
               end
            End;
         End;
         with DataModuleClient.ClntDSetGeneral do
         Begin
            Close;
            SQL.clear;
            SQL.Add('SELECT BILLNUMBER,BILLTYPE FROM BILLCANCELREQUEST WHERE BILLNUMBER = :BILLNUMBER AND BILLTYPE = :BILLTYPE');
            Params.ParamByName('BILLNUMBER').AsString :=
               Trim(ComboEditBillNumber.Text);
            Params.ParamByName('BILLTYPE').AsString :=
               QueryLookupBillType.FieldByname('BILLTYPE').AsString;
            Open;
            if Not IsEmpty then
            begin
               MessageDlg('Cannot return cancel requested bills !', mtWarning,
                  [MbOk], 0);
               Abort;
            end;
         End;
         With QueryGeneral Do
         Begin
            Close;
            SQL.clear;
            SQL.Add('SELECT CASHBILL, CREDITBILLTYPE, BILLNUMBER, BILLAMOUNT,BILLDISCOUNT,BILLDATE,PATIENTNAME FROM BILLMASTER WHERE BILLTYPE = '
               + '''' + QueryLookupBillType.FieldByname('BILLTYPE').AsString +
               '''' + ' AND BILLNUMBER = ' + '''' + ComboEditBillNumber.Text +
               '''' + ' AND BILLCANCELLED<>''' + 'Y' + '''');
            If FormSalesReturn.ComboEditOpNumber.Text <> '' Then
               SQL.Add(' AND OPNUMBER = ' + '''' +
                  FormSalesReturn.ComboEditOpNumber.Text + '''');
            Open;
            CurrencyBillAmount.Value := FieldByname('BILLAMOUNT').AsCurrency;
            if ((QueryGeneral.FieldByname('BILLDISCOUNT').AsCurrency <> 0.00) Or
               (QueryGeneral.FieldByname('BILLAMOUNT').AsCurrency <> 0.00)) then
               dBillDiscountPercentage :=
                  (FieldByname('BILLDISCOUNT').AsCurrency * 100) /
                  (FieldByname('BILLAMOUNT').AsCurrency +
                  FieldByname('BILLDISCOUNT').AsCurrency);
            If (FormMDIMain.sReturnPeriod > 0) And Not(IsEmpty) Then
            Begin
               With DataMain.QuerySysDate Do
               Begin
                  Close;
                  Params.ParamByName('BRANCHCODE').AsString :=
                     FormMDIMain.sBranchcode;
                  Open;
                  If ((StrToDate(FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy',
                     FieldByname('SYSDATE').AsDateTime)) -
                     StrToDate(FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy',
                     QueryGeneral.FieldByname('BILLDATE').AsDateTime))) >
                     FormMDIMain.sReturnPeriod) Then
                  Begin
                     MessageDlg
                        ('Item sold before the allowed time, cannot enter returns!',
                        mtInformation, [MbOk], 0);
                     ComboEditBillNumber.SetFocus;
                  End;
               End;
            End;

            If FieldByname('CASHBILL').AsString = IBRdGrpPaymentMode.Value Then
            Begin
               If FieldByname('CASHBILL').AsString = 'N' Then
               Begin
                  If Trim(IBComboGroupType.Text) = 'IPCREDIT' Then
                  Begin
                     If (Trim(FieldByname('CREDITBILLTYPE').AsString) <>
                        'IP CREDITS') Then
                     Begin
                        MessageDlg('payment mode variations found !',
                           mtInformation, [MbOk], 0);
                        ComboEditBillNumber.SetFocus;
                     End // Added on 26/05/2014
                     Else If (Trim(FieldByname('CREDITBILLTYPE').AsString)
                        = 'IP CREDITS') Then
                     Begin
                        with DataModuleClient.ClntDSetGeneral do
                        Begin
                           Close;
                           SQL.clear;
                           SQL.Add('SELECT DISCHARGED FROM IPMASTER WHERE IPNUMBER = :IPNUMBER AND IPSERIALNUMBER = :IPSERIALNUMBER');
                           Params.ParamByName('IPNUMBER').AsString :=
                              sOriginalIpNumber;
                           Params.ParamByName('IPSERIALNUMBER').AsString :=
                              IBEditSlNo.Text;
                           Open;
                           If (DataModuleClient.ClntDSetGeneral.FieldByname
                              ('DISCHARGED').AsString = 'Y') Then
                           Begin
                              If (lFlag = False) Then
                                 MessageDlg
                                    ('Since  patient is  discharged this bill should be saved as cash bill',
                                    mtWarning, [MbOk], 0);
                              lFlag := True;
                           End;
                        End;
                     End;
                  End
                  Else If IBComboGroupType.Text = 'OTHERS' Then
                  Begin
                     If ((Trim(FieldByname('CREDITBILLTYPE').AsString)
                        = 'CREDIT CARD') Or
                        (Trim(FieldByname('CREDITBILLTYPE').AsString)
                        = 'IP CREDITS')) Then
                     Begin
                        MessageDlg('payment mode variations found !',
                           mtInformation, [MbOk], 0);
                        ComboEditBillNumber.SetFocus;
                     End;
                  End;
               End;
            End;
            If FieldByname('CASHBILL').AsString <> IBRdGrpPaymentMode.Value Then
            Begin
               If (Trim(FieldByname('CREDITBILLTYPE').AsString)
                  = 'IP CREDITS') Then
               Begin
                  with DataModuleClient.ClntDSetGeneral do
                  Begin
                     Close;
                     SQL.clear;
                     SQL.Add('SELECT DISCHARGED FROM IPMASTER WHERE IPNUMBER = :IPNUMBER AND IPSERIALNUMBER = :IPSERIALNUMBER');
                     Params.ParamByName('IPNUMBER').AsString :=
                        sOriginalIpNumber;
                     Params.ParamByName('IPSERIALNUMBER').AsString :=
                        IBEditSlNo.Text;
                     Open;
                     If (DataModuleClient.ClntDSetGeneral.FieldByname
                        ('DISCHARGED').AsString <> 'Y') Then
                     Begin
                        MessageDlg('payment mode variations found !',
                           mtInformation, [MbOk], 0);
                        ComboEditBillNumber.SetFocus;
                     End;
                  End;
               End
               Else
               Begin
                  If (Trim(FieldByname('CREDITBILLTYPE').AsString) <>
                     'CREDIT CARD') Then
                  Begin
                     MessageDlg('payment mode variations found !',
                        mtInformation, [MbOk], 0);
                     ComboEditBillNumber.SetFocus;
                  End;
               End;
            End;
            If (IsEmpty) Then
            Begin
               ShowMessage('Bill Not Found!');
               ComboEditBillNumber.Text := '';
               ComboEditBillNumber.SetFocus;
            End
         End;
      End;
      QueryMaterials.Close;
      QueryMaterials.Open;
      If (QueryMaterials.FieldByname('BILLWISERETURN').AsString = 'Y') Then
      Begin
         If (Trim(IBLookupComboBillType.Text) <> '') And
            (Trim(ComboEditBillNumber.Text) <> '') Then
         Begin
            IBLookupComboBillItems.Enabled := True;
            CurrencyBillAmount.Enabled := True;
            EditFilter.Enabled := True;
         End
         Else
         Begin
            IBLookupComboBillItems.Enabled := False;
            CurrencyBillAmount.Enabled := False;
            EditFilter.Enabled := False;
         End;
      End
      Else
      Begin
         IBLookupComboBillItems.Enabled := True;
         CurrencyBillAmount.Enabled := True;
         EditFilter.Enabled := True;
      End;
      If EditFilter.Enabled Then
         EditFilter.SetFocus;
      QueryLookupItemName.Close;
   Except
      on E: Exception Do
      begin
         MessageDlg(E.Message, mtError, [MbOk], 0);
      end;

   End;
End;
```

Comment: Please can you fix the formatting. Read the help that is available whilst editing.

Comment: Reproduce this in the debugger and have a look at the stack. It will probably show you that one of your methods gets called recursively, and you will see where from and why.

Comment: ComboEditBillNumber.SetFocus; looks highly dodgy in the OnExit procedure. You could well trigger the OnExit again as the next control tries to gain focus, causing a stack overflow. I don't know for sure if this is the cause but it would be the first place I would look.

Comment: There seems to be *at least* one reason for a stack overflow in the (horrendously complicated) code you posted, which is the repeated use of `SetFocus` to move to other controls, which is probably causing the `OnExit` event of the current code to be reentered. As an aside, I'm really surprised your users haven't revolted; it must take forever to simply tab between controls with queries being run, and the focus jumping all over the screen to various locations unpredictably would be really annoying. My users would be beating me with their keyboards by now.

Comment: @KenWhite: You need to move further away from your users ;)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: If my app used this validation technique, they'd pool their money to find a way to track me down. ;)